# Using Merge-fields With force.com site to relate a form to a record

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, form, merge-field

**Project**

Build a form off salesforce that can be sent to clients to collect information. A user will Send an email off the account record containing a link to the form. The form will allow clients to update their information (but not see existing values). Then "submit."

**Things I need advice with**

1. How to use merge-fields with the force.com sites link to relate an
   external form to an account. (Or even if theres even a better method through a controller etc..)

   (in dev console when i click preview I normally can just append &id=" ")
2. What type of profile to set up to allow the receiver of the link to update the fields via the form.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to use merge-fields with the force.com sites link to relate an external form to an account. (Or even if theres even a better method through a controller etc..)**

**A:** The link will contain the AccountId in URL params, In your VF page you will retrieve that accountID, then querry the data and then show to the user accordingly. All this will happen in constructor of custom controller.
    As you are running it as a Force.com, you have to make your apex classs as **without sharing**

**What type of profile to set up to allow the receiver of the link to update the fields via the form.?**

**A**: As you are using force.com sites, the default profile will be force.com site guest user profile. Only provide access of VF page and the controller class to that profile.

Best practise is to send encrypted AccountId to the end user so that he/she is not able to autoincrement certain Id and update someone else's data

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your post helped clarify a few concepts I had confused In my head. Have you seen any helpful links flying around relating to sending an encrypted account id? @Pranay Jaiswal

Comment: This link teaches about how to encrypt and decrypt.
http://salesforceworld4u.blogspot.com/2014/01/encryption-and-decryption-in-salesforce.html

Comment: your the man thank you for deciphering what I was looking for.  Super Appreciated.